# Find the shortest distance d between these two lines

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Let $L1$ be the line passing through the point $P1=(-2,-11,$9) with direction vector $d2=[0,2,-2]^T$, and let $L2$ be the line passing through the point $P2 = (-2, -1, 11)$ with direction vector $d2 = [-1, 0, -1]^T $
Find the shortest distance $d$ between these two lines, and find a point $Q1$ on $L1$ and a point $Q2$ on $L2$ so that $d(Q1,Q2) = d.$ Use the square root symbol to get the exact value

Comment: For a start, you need to find the equation of the plane that contain both direction vectors of the lines. If one line is entirely in the plane, the question is reduced to finding the distance between a line (not in the plane) and the plane. Now think perpendiculars

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework problem. This isn’t a homework-answering site. Adding your own attempts to solve the problem to your question will make it more likely to attract answers and allow people who do answer to craft ones that you’ll understand.